# TFS plug-in for Eclipse ( Team Explorer Everywhere) in Ubuntu, does not reflect the changes made correctly

Tags: linux, ubuntu, tfs, tee, team-explorer-everywhere

I have installed Team Explorer Everywhere (TFS plug-in for Eclipse) on an Eclipse Lunar on Ubuntu. I am connected to our company's TFS server at XYZ.visualstudio.com and I can successfully connect and browse the files.

When I make changes to a file, I expect the plug-in to automatically check it out and detect if I have made any changes. Unfortunately it doesn't. "Pending changes" section only shows the files that are explicitly checked out. And it doesn't end here! It shows ALL checked out files as "Edited" even though they haven't been touched. Of course if I check in all the files, it only checks in the modified ones, that's cool. However I cannot see exactly what are the changes in the change set. 
I tried the same scenario in Eclipse on Windows. That works fine. As soon as I edit a file, even outside Eclipse, it detect the change and adds the file to the list of pending changes.  Interestingly, in Linux scenario, there is not even a "Detect Local Changes" in Action menu.

Why the plug-in behaves like this? Is it a bug? Am I missing anything?

PS: I have tried the following, didn't help:
- I closed and reopened Eclipse before and after modifying the file.
- I chmod my files to a+rw 
- I ran Eclipse as root

Versions:

Ubuntu: 14.04

Kernel: 3.13.0-4-generic

Eclipse: Luna 4.4.1

TFS plug-in: 12.0.2

The plug-in menu in Eclipse-Linux
The plug-in menu in Eclipse-Windows

Comment: How did you get started?  Did you Import from TFS or did you just import an existing project?  If you right click on a file in package explorer, is there anything in the Team menu?

Comment: Hey Edward. Yes we already are hosting our projects on TFS cloud. So I connected to our repository and "cloned" it on my Ubuntu machine. What "package explorer" are you talking about? I couldn't quite follow. Could you be more specific please?

Comment: You cloned it?  Is your project in TFVC or Git?

Comment: No, TFS. It's a TFVC. I shouldnt have used a Git-Term! my bad!